# Is there in JSF a standard way to add an HTTP header to all queries?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jwt, myfaces

Is there a standard mechanism in JSF 2.2 allowing me to include an HTTP header in all HTTP requests, regular or partial ?

I am looking for a solution to have the content of the "Authentication" header copied from the server reply and added to all queries. This way, I could easily use JWT tokens in my JSF apps.

If there is no standard mechanism, one specific to MyFaces 2.2 would be a solution too.

Comment: Does it really have to be a JSF-tight-coupled approach? A simple servlet filter should already do.

Comment: It does not have to be JSF thight, you are right. AFAIK, a servlet filter will allow me to process the input or modify the reply, not to tell the browser which header it should include.